# Visual C++ memory management changes between VS 2008 and VS 2017

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, memory, buffer-overflow

We recently migrated quite a large piece of software written mainly in C (some parts are C++) from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2017. Most of the software originates from the 80s / early 90s.

While testing the new binaries we keep running into bugs caused by memory overflows. These memory overflows seem to have been in there forever but apparently never exposed themselves under older versions of the MSVC compiler. While it is good that they are found and fixed, it would be nice to know what causes these to be exposed now.

Did the memory management of Visual C change a lot between 2008 and 2017? Can anyone point me towards documentation on this subject?

Comment: Couldn't you just track down the source-code for `malloc` & `realloc`?

Comment: @enhzflep: these are not open sourced.

Comment: IMHO it‘s useless to read such documentation. A bug is a bug and it can manifest itself after tomorrow’s compiler update.

Comment: More "daring" optimisations is a favorite thing for any new version of a compiler. Even if the optimisations are safe, they could expose more weaknesses the more daring they are.

Comment: Maybe some compiler flag are now set by default, like /Zc:sizedDealloc

Comment: Not related to this but, i keep hearing that it is very difficult to migrate projects from 2008 to newer versions of visual studio.Is it that difficult?

Comment: @enhzflep The project is too large for that, and over the years different styles of memory management have been used.

Comment: It could be difficult to migrate C++ projects as VC++ compiler became more standard conformant over these years and uses C++14 mode by default. So stuff like assignment of string literal to `char *` and `auto_ptr` are now hard errors.

Comment: @manni66 I don't think it will help us find the issues earlier, but it would help us explain to the management why it takes so much time.

Comment: I'm going to say that [address space randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) is not your friend. You should make sure it's not enabled for your executable.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks! I'll have a look into that.

Comment: @GauravSehgal In our case most work was in updating the dependencies (like Boost, Xalan, Xerces). Interestingly enough the newer parts of the product written in C++ caused more issues that the older C parts (other than these memory overflow issues). An example was a windows service written using ATL where the ATL base class changes causing our service to not shutdown any more..

Comment: @Harm: You also might want to consider  using smart pointers in C++11 onward (like 'std::shared_ptr'). This would avoid/reduce the need to manage the memory.

Comment: @Yves - Even though MSVC is not "open source" (=free to modify), the runtime source is provided with the compiler.

Comment: @BoPersson: never seen that !

Comment: Impossible to say if you don't post examples.  You say they were not exposed under older versions of the "compiler", but then you say they are exposed during testing. My guess is that the standard library (Dinkumware) code is detecting the overflows. Or it could be that the new/delete library code is doing it.

Comment: The most recent example was one where data was written outside the boundaries of an array. This was overwriting another global variable (pointer) being accessed a lot later causing an access violation.
<pre>
int32 scopes[32];
...
int i = 45;
scopes[i] = 0;
</pre>

Answer (score 3):

The most relevant compiler option would be `/GS`, which is a buffer security check. This intentionally tries to detect the sort of problem you're describing, because these class of problems often end up as exploitable security issues. Crashing early is a better alternative.